# ffmpeg concat give Non-monotonous DTS in output stream

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

Env: Windows7, ffmpeg 4.2.2

```
copy the first 10 seconds from long.mp4 to UNO.mp4
copy sec 120 to sec 130 from long.mp4 to DUE.mp4
```

create List.txt with

```
file 'C:\Users\Admin\Videos\UNO.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\Admin\Videos\DUE.mp4'
```

here the ffprobe output of the two files:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'UNO.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 671 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 536 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 09/18/2020.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 09/18/2020.

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'DUE.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 657 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 524 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 09/18/2020.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 09/18/2020.
```

use the two files as input to

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "C:\Users\Admin\Videos\List.txt" -c copy "C:\Users\Admin\Videos\mergedVideo.mp4"
```

it outputs:

```
mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00be7f80] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
nput #0, concat, from 'C:\Users\Admin\Videos\List.txt':
 Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 825 kb/s
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 624x352 [SAR 1:1 DAR 39:22], 697 kb/s, 25 fps, 25
tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : VideoHandler
   Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : SoundHandler
utput #0, mp4, to 'C:\Users\Admin\Videos\mergedVideo.mp4':
 Metadata:
   encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 624x352 [SAR 1:1 DAR 39:22], q=2-31, 697 kb/s, 25
fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : VideoHandler
   Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : SoundHandler
tream mapping:
 Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
 Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
```

then a long series of :

```
mp4 @ 00c43c40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 899370, current: 720000; changing to 899371. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

at end as last messages :

```
rame=  552 fps=528 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2220kB time=00:00:20.01 bitrate= 908.4kbits/s speed=19.2x
ideo:1873kB audio:329kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.827539%
```

When i play the output mergedVideo.mp4 with ffplay, it does not gove errors
it is only a time stamp problem, or some frames or some audio are lost ?
in the latter case, is there a parameter to correct the problem, or i have to re-encode ?
(to further test, i tried with avidemux an it concats UNO.mp4 and DUE.mp4 without re-encoding)

Thanks in advance to all for the support
Maurizio

Comment: Have you checked the codec configurations of two files? concat expects that ["All files must have the same streams (same codecs, same time base, etc.)."](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1)

Comment: Hi.. i repeat
the two files comes from a mother file..
i cut first 10 seconds from long.mp4 to UNO.mp4  
i cut sec 120 to sec 130 from long.mp4 to DUE.mp4 
if i concat with avidemux it give no problems..it does not reencode..
the problem is very strange

Comment: To further testing i downloaded ffmpeg 4.4.. but nothing changes, i tried with as lomg.mp4 a video downloaded from youtube, cutting in in two parts and then concat,but the results are always the same, i still get error messages, and the merged video output is missing form tha last two seconds of the UNO.mp4 .. any help will be appreciated.. thanks in advance

Comment: i updated the first post with the output of ffprobe, the codecs and the format are the same... the problem is with a video downloaded from youtube and edted with ffmpeg to create two files, the problems happens with every video and can be easily reproduced..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, unless you call FFmpeg with the `-xerror` option (which you didn't) "Non-monotonous DTS..." message is not an error. It's just a warning. It is just informing what it's doing for you, and thankfully its automatic adjustment indeed worked for your case base on your description.

It is making the adjustment because you are concatenate-and-copying streams, of which data frame carries timestamp (unlike WAV or MPEG streams). The `concat` demuxer likely cannot adjust the timestamp in the stream data on the fly (to avoid the warnings/corrections from the main `ffmpeg` program).

The bottom line. If the warning messages must go, change the log level to ignore warning: `-loglevel error`.

Reference [`ffmpeg.c` Lines 817-834](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/68595b46cb374658432fff998e82e5ff434557ac/fftools/ffmpeg.c)

Comment: Hi..  thanks for the answer. i tried -xerror but the result is: Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 127488, current: 103936; aborting.
Conversion failed!
as i described in my second cooments:                                                                          i tried with as lomg.mp4 a video downloaded from youtube, 
cutting in in two parts: UNO.mp4 DUE.mp4 and then concat
the merged video output is missing form tha last two seconds of the UNO.mp4 ..

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about last 2 seconds of the UNO.mp4 missing. Could you try different format for UNO.mp4 and DUE.mp4? Say UNO.mkv and DUE.mkv. This will check if it is the container issue or codec issue. If this singles out that mp4 is the issue, you need to resort to `concat` filter

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.. i tried also using as long.mp3 another file downloaded from the network,the results is the same, in the  mean time i tried  with intermediate files and it works ! i do not know if this info with help you to diagnose because i'm not a multimedia expert , i will change the container to mkv and provide a feedback..

Comment: Hi i was of some days.. today i tried with mkv and it works ..  now i will create anothe post with thw commands i issued..

Comment: i cut the original file to .mkv files ,and then concat them,it works ! ... to avoid confusion i will open another question with only essential data, with this data the problem can be easily reproduced by anyone, and a new question with no answer can can be more support ..  up to now thanks to kesh

Comment: Converting to .mkv before concat also fixed all my problems